# Acumatica Menu Items Disabled Due to New Document Status

Tags: acumatica

Currently I am enhancing the CRCase screen (CR306000) as I need to add a new status for a case, as I require a new state between Open and Closed. In the DAC Extension for the CRCase, I implemented a new string list which contains the old statuses together with the new ones.

The problem is that whenever the case document is in the new status, every action under the actions and inquiries action group is set to disabled. I tried to enable these actions in the extension row selected event but they remain disabled. Even though, in the graph the enabled flag is set to true when debugged.

Comment: can you show some code that you've created for this?